# SwiftUI Resize width and height when switching Views

Tags: macos, swiftui, frame, window-resize

There are two Views in my ContentView. Views are different in size, but Thread errors occur when view change. How can I change the size dynamically?
Here is my code I've used fixedSize(), but it doesn't work.

```
var body: some View {
    if !changeLogin {
        LoginMasterView(changeLogin: $changeLogin, frameSize: $frameSize)
            .environmentObject(cloudoc)
            .environmentObject(drive)
            //initial frame size(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 640)
    } else {
        ExplorerScreen(changeLogin: $changeLogin)
            .environmentObject(cloudoc)
            .environmentObject(drive)
            .background(Color.systemBackground.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            .frame(minWidth: 720, idealWidth: 720, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 640, idealHeight: 640, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .fixedSize()       
    }
    
}
```

How do I make the frame resizing without any errors?